# how to dynamically generate JSon object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I was trying to send/receive JSon between client and server.

I generated JSon (I thought) by a function

```
    self.gen_data=function()
    {   //create request data
        var input_array =self.input_value();  
        myJson={ 
                request_type:1,   //send request for problem 1
                data_list:{}
               };

        for(var k=0;k<input_array.length;k++)
        {
            myJson.data_list[k]=input_array[k];  //a number in array
        }
        console.log(myJson);
        return myJson;

    }
```

can't read it on server

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: self.serverURI,
        data: JSON.stringify(self.gen_data()),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) 
        {
            //console.log(result);
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            //alert(result.a);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
        {
                console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

on server

```
var data=req.body;

console.log("request_type: ",req.body.request_type);

console.log("data_list size: ",data.data_list.length);

/*
for(var i=0;i<data.data_list.length;i++)
{
    console.log(data.data_list[k]);
}
*/
```

but it displayed as:

```
  data_list size:  undefined
```

try to read array elements caused error.

Comment: JSON.stringify() returns a JSON string, but it seems you want the JSON object?

Comment: @unicorn2 I am confused with send/receiving, how to read JSon content at server and client. could you give an example? I will be thankful for it.

Comment: @alim, try to add `processData: false` option, or pass the JSON via some key, e.g.: `data: { json: JSON.stringify(self.gen_data()) }`

Comment: @alim: Try without JSON.stringify: data: self.gen_data(),
Have a look at this example, you are post correctly https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @unicorn2 Great. without JSon.stringfy(..), I am able to receive on server and read its field. Finally. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON.stringify()` returns a JSON string, but it seems you want the JSON object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Try without `JSON.stringify`:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: self.serverURI,
        data: self.gen_data(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) 
        {
            //console.log(result);
            alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            //alert(result.a);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
        {
                console.log(xhr);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I changed the gen_data() and failing to read its list on server. could u take a look please?

Comment: self.input_value() is returning an array [1,4,5,6,8]. I printed on client side, it has no problem.

Comment: I assume your server is node.js?

Comment: Hi, I fixed it.  make it an array "  data_list:[]"  then it worked. :)  you helped a lot, thanks. Yes, I am using node.js

Comment: Glad I could help :)